# rostopic pub /topic_name sensor_msgs/JointState [arguments]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I run this command line:

```
rostopic pub servo sensor_msgs/JointState '{header: {seq:0, stamp: {secs:0, nsecs:0}, frame_id:""}, name:["art1"],position:[150.0], velocity:[0.0], effort:[0.0]}' --once

and i get the following error:


emilio@emilio-N61Vg:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic pub servo sensor_msgs/JointState '{header: {seq:0, stamp: {secs:0, nsecs:0}, frame_id:""}, name:["art1"],position:[150.0], velocity:[0.0], effort:[0.0]}' --once

Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: Argument error: while scanning a plain scalar

  in "<string>", line 1, column 11:

    {header: {seq:0, stamp: {secs:0, nsecs:0}, ... 
              ^

found unexpected ':'

  in "<string>", line 1, column 14:

    {header: {seq:0, stamp: {secs:0, nsecs:0}, fr ... 
                 ^

Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215769/rostopic-pub-/topic_name-sensor_msgs/jointstate-%5Barguments%5D/) by [Emilio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23551/emilio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the question is "What is wrong with this command?", right?

Try with:

```
rostopic pub servo sensor_msgs/JointState '{header: {seq: 0, stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}, frame_id: ""}, name: ["art1"], position: [150.0], velocity: [0.0], effort: [0.0]}' --once
```

Note the space after each `:`. This is mandatory!

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23551/emilio/) on 2015-08-13**:
That works, thank you!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-13**:
please mark the answer as correct, if it helped :-)

**Comment by [Emilio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23551/emilio/) on 2015-08-13**:
sorry, this is the first time i post here ;)